# Посылка USB транзакций

Tags: windows, usb, драйвер

Нужно сгенерировать транзакцию на контроллере ehci направленную на конкретное устройство (device:endpoint), причем устройство может как существовать, так и нет.

Из документации на ehci контроллер видно, чтобы создать транзакцию на шине необходимо просто знать адрес устройства, его скорость и поставить транзакцию в очередь. Я реализовал такую штуку на контроллере из драйвера, но так и не смог разойтись со штатным драйвером ОС Windows, штатный драйвер просто умирал и завешивал контроллер. Теперь хочу это повторить используя средства ОС и не знаю куда копать. Я попробовал user-mode libusb в связке с драйвером libusbK.sys, но они работают только с зарегистрированными устройствами и если устройства нет, то отваливаются с ошибкой раньше, не создавая транзакцию.Плюс они посылают запрос через весь стек драйверов USB (не знаю хорошо это или плохо).

В данный момент я рассматриваю возможность написания драйвера с посылкой URB (USB Request Block),но не знаю приведет ли это к успеху. Соответственно хочу узнать у уважаемых коллег, ковырялся ли кто-то с подобной задачей и какие результаты получились.

Ведь в принципе драйвер usbehci.sys тоже обрабатывает запросы, которые сведены к тому минимуму, что мне нужно, но как узнать его интерфейс кроме дизассемблирования?

А также может существует еще какой-то метод о котором я не подумал?

Comment: Максимум, что я могу посоветовать в винде - получить список устройств, найти нужно имя (или взять имя с диспечера устройств) и попытаться отправить пакет посредством `DeviceIoControl`.

Comment: Мне нужно то сделать сильно ниже, через DeviceIoControl можно трогать только зарегистрированное устройство и вызов пройдет кучу проверок, а они мне помешают.